# unicode conversion and export in R

Tags: r, unicode

I have created a script below for converting unicode into chinese characters, the last string in `temp.df[,"name_unicode"]` is "§®£" (without quote), so that people not knowing chinese can also help.

```
library(RODBC)
library(Unicode)

temp.df <- data.frame(name_unicode=c("&#38515;&#22823;&#25991;",
                                     "&#38515;&#23567;&#25935;",
                                     "&#38515;&#19968;&#23665;",
                                     "&#167;&#174;&#163;"),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

temp.df[,"name_unicode_mod"] <- sapply(temp.df[,"name_unicode"],
                                        function(x) {
                                          temp <- unlist(strsplit(x,";"))
                                          temp <- sprintf("%x",as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]","",temp)))
                                          temp <- intToUtf8(as.u_char_range(temp))
                                          return(temp)
                                          })


write.csv(temp.df,file("test.csv",encoding="UTF-8"),row.names=FALSE)
```

The output for `temp.df[,"name_unicode_mod"]` is OK for R console. But I need to export them out in `csv` or `xls` format. I tried `write.csv`, `write.table`, `odbcConnectExcel` in `RODBC` but all gives me something like `<U+00A7><U+00AE><U+00A3>`.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

P.S. I am using R 3.0.0 and Win7

Comment: Have you tried also using the `encoding` argument in the `write.table` function?

Comment: tried: `out <- file("test.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8"); write.table(temp.df, out, row.names=FALSE); close(out)`

still fail

Comment: +1 because I feel your pain with encoding.

Answer (score 5):

Using a binary writing will work for your case. 
The following is a small sample code to do.

```
writeUtf8csv <- function(x, file) {
  con <- file(file, "wb")
  apply(x, 1, function(a) {
      b <- paste(paste(a, collapse=','), '\r\n', sep='')
      writeBin(charToRaw(b), con, endian="little")
    })
  close(con)
}
```

More details are shown in [this reference page](http://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows/).