# How to convert special characters into unicode in R?

Tags: r, character-encoding, special-characters

When doing some textual data cleaning in R, I can found some special characters. In order to get rid of them, I have to know their unicodes, for example € is \u20AC. I would like to know if it is possible "see" the unicodes with a function that take into account the string within the special character as an input?

Comment: The following posts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761858/converting-a-u-escaped-unicode-string-to-ascii) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028658/unicode-conversion-and-export-in-r) may shed some light on the issue. Also, in an internet search, I came across a package called "Unicode" that may be worth a gander.

Comment: you may also try function `iconv`

Comment: what is the original encoding?

Comment: the original encoding is utf-8. In console, I can see "é" correctly, however, using iconv, I have "Ã©"; I would like to see "\u00E9".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace accented characters in R with non-accented counterpart (UTF-8 encoding)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495598/replace-accented-characters-in-r-with-non-accented-counterpart-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

```
special_char <- "%"
Unicode::as.u_char(utf8ToInt(special_char))
```

Answer (score 1):

Refering to Cath comment, `iconv` can do the job :

```
iconv("é", toRaw = TRUE)
```

Then, you may want to `unlist` and paste with `\u00`.