# converting special characters to plain text

Tags: r

I have a text file with special charactes. 
I want to replace all the instance of [image] by [image]
this is how i read my file

> donnees <- read.table("Shanghaifr.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)

and I get this 
[image: sample of my table]

I tried this but it did not work

```html
    donnees <- read.table("Shanghaifr.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)
    datest <- donnees$datesr[[15]]
    sub("ao<U+00FB>","ao\\U00FBt",datest)
```

I'm supposed to get 17août2017 for example so that i can easily do later

> as.Date("17août2017", "%d%b%Y")# to get the numeric date.

Comment: maybe do a sub? ie `sub("<U+OOFB>","Aug",datatest$date)` then convert to data format

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. I just tried it didn’t change anything . Maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703291/how-to-convert-special-characters-into-unicode-in-r. I would suggest re-framing the question (e.g. "converting special characters to plain text") and provide some sample data so people can try on more than just one instance e.g. other accents, chapeau etc.

Comment: R would understand the following format / escaping: `as.Date("21ao\u00FBt2017", "%d%b%Y")`

Comment: @Gautam I try to edit with more details. I read the link u suggested but it didn't really help. I was not able to change the special character

Comment: @RolandASc thank you. I know. But my problem is actually how to edit <U+00FB> to \U00FB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sub` seems a bit tricky here, because of the encoding it might do. E.g.:

```
sub("ao<U+00FB>t", "ao\u00FBt", "21ao<U+00FB>t2017", fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "21aoÃ»t2017"
```

Possible work-around could be (there must be a more elegant way?!):

```
sub("<U\\+00FB>", enc2native("\u00FB"), "21ao<U+00FB>t2017")
# [1] "21août2017"
```

Comment: Merciiiiii thank you.. the one with enc2native worked very well. I had first to change my local LC_CTYPE to "French_France.1252" and then everything was ok. thank u a lot