# How to decode HTML encoding of accented letters? (&ampeacute)

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding

I have a vector coming from an external database that had a problem with encoding, resulting in a character vector with many occurrences of `&ampXXX`.

This looks like HTML encoding of accented letters.

Is there a function that can convert this to a readable vector?

Obviously, `iconv()` is not working as the very encoding seems right. `Encoding(x)` returns `unknown` though.

Here is a little reprex with the expected output:

```r
x="H&ampeacutemipl&ampeacutegie"
iconv(x, from="latin1", to="utf8") #no effect
"Hémiplégie" #expected outcome
```

Comment: it is "escaping" (so no proper encoding), in any case, HTML would have a ; at the end of the "entity" (the name of used by HTML). Check https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/htmltools/html/htmlEscape.html -- link wrong. it is the reverse. But it is an duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724885/convert-html-entity-to-proper-character-r

Comment: If the string were properly formatted, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060076/convert-html-character-entity-encoding-in-r would also work. But what you have isn't any sort of valid encoded HTML entity. It should be more like `x="H&eacute;mipl&eacute;gie"`

Comment: Yeah, I though I had the "encoding" word wrong, thanks. And indeed, this nasty database comes from a nasty software, and that's not the worst it can do :-(

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi my vector lacks the `;` so `read_html()` doesn't work. I guess I will have to do it manually with `str_replace()` then...

Comment: Yeah. Or check the origin of data (possibly the `;` was lost in some conversions